# Given an IP url, can I find url endpoints

Tags: windows, ip, webserver, directory-listing

I have an IP address with a webpage on it, reachable from the Internet.

I do not have any other information about it.
How can I find other URL endpoints associated with it?

Example`http://999.99.99.999/`

It displays a default page, it is a windows server, but FTP times out, SSH times out, and I don't know any of the directory names.

How can I find out other things, such as other publicly accessible directories, without asking the system administrator who may be unavailable or incompetent?

Comment: Usually, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily... but there are tools that might help.  For example, a reverse DNS lookup may give you one hostname associated with the machine.  Also, http://robtex.com is a helpful tool that may be able to find out more based on the IP address (i.e. what network it's on, what other machines are on the same network that robtex knows about), etc.  But in short, the only definitive way to determine all the associate URLs is to have administrative access to the machine and look at the server configuration.  For example, since you know you're on a Windows machine, you would probably want to try Remote Desktop (RDP) or a CIFS file share.